# How to get rid of this white border in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I'm trying to style a table in MS Word (Mac, 2019 version if relevant).

I'm 99% there - but there seems to be a thin white border at the bottom of my header row, and also at the bottom of the table that I can't get to go away...

EDIT: Example doc with the table here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sr1ihuh6xsz5e0g/example%20table.docx?dl=0

[image: image of table in word with thin white border below intentional blue background shade]

I have the table heading row set to have a 3px border around the 4 blue columns only and the same blue background shading in place. If I remove the top blue border from the cell below the white gap disappears. But I did want the blue line there in place.

Screenshot of the 'borders' drop down from Word here:
[image: image showing border drop-down preferences from MS word for mac]

Comment: Please post online an example document.

Comment: @harrymc I've added an example doc on a dropbox link in the original post. Thanks for any tips you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's only a visual effect created by a dpi-scaling issue. Zoom in and out of your page, and you will see the border appear and disappear.

If you want to get comletely rid of it, the only way is to insert a rectangle, fill it with the same blue color and place it behind your table, selecting "wrap text -> behind text" from the shape format menu. (see screenshot below)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! You're absolutely right about it being a dpi-scaling thing. I wish I'd posted sooner after fighting it for so long yesterday...